# Typescript Cant observe response from POST but can from get?

Tags: typescript, httpclient

Using typescript I have 2 consecutive calls:
GET:

```
this.httpClient.get<string>('http://localhost:8080/token',
      {
        observe: 'response'
      })
    .subscribe(resp => {console.log(resp);});
```

POST:

```
this.httpClient.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/hello',{observe: 'response' }).subscribe(resp => {
      console.log(resp);})
  }
```

Here is the GET response:

```
HttpResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', url: 'http://customer1.workflow.com:8070/token', ok: true, …}
```

Here is the POST response:

```
{errors: Array(0), results: 'D1C71355B8FAFA7BA505AF50697C4D9C'}
```

The POST response is just the body and I can't workout why....

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. With the post() method the body needs to be the first argument after the URI:

```
this.httpClient.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/hello',{}, 
{observe: 'response' }).subscribe(resp => {
      console.log(resp);})
  }
```

returns:

```
{headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', url: 'http:...'}
```